# Flutter BloC SignIn Navigation

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, bloc

I'm using Firebase for Authentication and created Blocs for Authentication, Signin and Signup. There are basically four screens: AuthScreen which decides to return SignIn or HomePage, and SignUpScreen, which is only accessible from SignInScreen.

Signin is working properly, but when I navigate from Signin to Signup page and authentication is successfully, I get not forwarded to the HomePage.

This is my AuthScreen:

```
class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state.status == AuthenticationStatus.authenticated) {
          return MultiBlocProvider(
            providers: [
              BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => SignInBloc(
                    authRepository:
                        context.read<AuthenticationBloc>().authRepository),             
            ],
            child: HomePage(),
          );
        } else {
          return MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
            BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => SignInBloc(
                    authRepository:
                        context.read<AuthenticationBloc>().authRepository)
            )
          ], 
          child: SignInScreen());
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

`AuthenticationStatus` gets updated from a stream. When SignIn is completed I get forwarded to the HomePage, but when I switch from `SignInScreen` to `SignUpScreen` not, even I can see in the debugger that the `AuthenticationStatus` gets updated and `HomePage` is returned.

This is how I navigate from SignInScreen to SignUpScreen:

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context){
        return BlocProvider<SignUpBloc>(
        create: (context) => SignUpBloc(
          authRepository: context.read<AuthenticationBloc>().authRepository
        ),
        child: const SignUpScreen(),
      );                               
    },
  ),
);
```

The same to get back to SignInScreen from SignUpScreen:

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context){
        return BlocProvider<SignInBloc>(
        create: (context) => SignInBloc(
          authRepository: context.read<AuthenticationBloc>().authRepository
        ),
        child: const SignInScreen (),
      );                               
    },
  ),
);
```

Signin is working properly, when I switch to SignUp screen and a new user is registered, the HomePage is return in AuthScreen, but it's not visible for the user.
In the BlocObserver I also see that the Blocs get new created every time I swirtch between SignIn and SignUp Screen, how can I close them after navigating to another screen?

Comment: Can you post the bloc code?

Answer (score 0):

You are using bad practice using bloc.
You should not use blocProvider in the navigator you must use blocProvider in each screen (SignInScreen and SignUpScreen) and create its bloc as a separated.

It would help you if use dependency injection to create bloc
you can use [getIt](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) package for dependency injection like blow

```
class SignInScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
        BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => getIt<SignInBloc>())
    ],
    child: HomePage());
  }
}
```

in this case, if you use dependency injection authRepository can be injected automatically into SignInBloc

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the BlocProvider for SignInScreen in the AuthScreen, so shall I wrap the SignUpScreen with a BlocProvider inside it, to be able to just navigate to it from SignInScreen?